# Data Migration in BUs

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data-migration, package-manager

I am trying to move all data (sendable /non sendable)related to particular market from existing BU to new BU created.I have already moved the structure using Package Manager.
How the data can be moved? Provided the data will keep on updating in existing BU.

Comment: Why don't you create common fileLocation in your Parent BU... and use it as an EXTERNAL FTP to import and export from your required BUs.

Comment: With an App? Email? SMS? Push ... we need more details.